# can't connect my jQuery with html

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I am unable to connect my JS to my HTML. Can someone please let me know what am I doing wrong in this code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Todo List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Assest/css/Todo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Assest/js/Lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Assest/js/Todo.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>    
</body>
</html>
```

```html
body {
    background: white;
}
```

```
// doesn't work
alert("CONNECT!");
```

Result of inspecting `jQuery`:

```
ƒ (e,t){
     return new w.fn.init(e,t)
}
$("li")
w.fn.init [li, prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]
```

Comment: There's no reason that a simple `alert()` wouldn't work unless there's an error in your code. Check the console. Also check the URL to the files is correct, it seems like `Assest` should be `Assets`, and should also be made relative to the root folder, not the current folder.

Comment: Please check your console and see what error is there

Comment: alert isn't even from jquery, its from javascript it self. Check your console for errors. In Chrome you can check your console using the F12 button and selecting console

Comment: alert is not related to jquery. At what action you are calling this alert?